# Manual adding module to virtualenv [django,python]

Tags: python, django, module, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv which contains a django project.
I want to add a module made by myself called `RandomTools.py`.
By dropping the file to the virtualenv's `\Lib\site-packages` folder,and running the project through the virtualenv, I get a

> ImportError: No module named RandomTools.py

Where shuld I put that module file ?

Comment: are you using `import RandomTools` or `import RandomTools.py` in your code?

Comment: `import RandomTools` , but they both not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a folder for your module instead of dropping the file straight into \Lib\site-packages.

For instance, you may want to name the folder : RandomToolsFolder

inside RandomTools,

you must have a  `__init__.py` file to allow indicate that this directory is a module file. In the same directory you can place your RandomTools.py file.

Therefore your import statement will be

```
    from RandomToolsFolder import RandomTools
```

Comment: It is still not working.... But I see that modules such as `"os.py"` are a singel `.py` file.. why can't I do so?

Comment: sorry formatting error the file should be be called `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a setup.py file for your module.

Folder struct:

```
/
/setup.py
/RandomTools/*
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "RandomTools",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
)
```

You can then just install your RandomTools with `python setup.py install`

You can read the full documentation [here](http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide)

Comment: is it still valid nowadays or the setup.py should be different ?